# Drupal textfield input limiting

Tags: drupal, textfield, character, words, limits

My client wants to limit the input into a textfield to 16 words - I have no idea how to achieve this.

In addition, he wants to disble characters from being part of the input.
In other words, allow only 16 words and with no special characters.

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: are you using drupal from api?

Comment: @Hira: No, I haven't got any solution right now. I just figured out I can have a CCK textfield limited to 16 characters but ofcourse these need to be just words.

Comment: there is maximum length option you can set it to 16 in text cck field no idea about special character although there is an option of allowed value list you could try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unusual use case and in a quick search I don't see that there is a module that provides these particular limits for a Drupal 7 field. I think you will need to write a custom module which adds a field widget where you can set limits for number of words and allowed characters (well, making this configurable would make a much more useful module that could be re-used and shared). You could use Regex in your validation function. Javascript / jQuery could be used to dynamically check the word count, use of allowed characters and/or character count limits for the field.

If you don't know how to write such a module, you can describe your requirements on any of the several sites which exist for hiring freelancers and get a quote for the work... then ideally make the module "community contributed".

Comment: my thoughts exactly! I haven't looked into all the parts but I hope I can use jquery to execute regualr expressions and intercept the node save process to stop the user from saving the node if there happens to be any special characters. I hope I can get the module working and released - not quite a prolific module developer yet

Comment: Right. The Field API provides a hook_field_validate() function which you'd use to determine whether entry is "valid". It can be helpful to look at existing (core and contrib) modules for examples of implementation. The [Examples for Developers module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) is a good place to start, besides looking at the modules within the core "Field" module.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

Use [field validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module.

Answer (score 1):

A Drupal 7 module does actually exist, and seems to do what you're looking for:

http://drupal.org/project/maxlength